# Submit App with cocoapods to itunesconnect

Tags: xcode, swift, google-analytics, cocoapods

I have an Xcode Workspace with my app and cocoapods for Google Analytics. I would like to upload the app to the app store with Google Analytics. Should I just click archive in the menu at the top and upload as I usually do or do I need to do anything to include the cocoapods? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cocoapods installs itself as a static library built as a dependency of your app. So just building for release (ie. Archiving) should work as before.

If you successfully ran your app in Debug on a device with Google Analytics before, there is no reason for Archiving to fail.

Even if your project was somehow mis-configured, as long as you are using a Google Analytics class or function in your app, if the pod doesn't get compiled and linked the whole app compilation will fail due to missing symbols.